# Can't install ingress-merge with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Following the install instructions I can not install "ingress-merge".

I first tried :

```
helm install --namespace kube-system --name ingress-merge ./helm
```

That gave me the error - "Error: unknown flag: --name"

I searched that issue up and found out that the --name flag is no longer needed.

I next tried the following:

```
helm install ingress-merge --namespace kube-system ./helm
```

That gave me the error - `Error: path "./helm" not found`
I then took out the `./helm`:

```
helm install ingress-merge --namespace kube-system
```

That gave me the error - `Error: must either provide a name or specify --generate-name`

What is the correct command structure?

Here is the link with the install instructions:
https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge

Comment: what is the output of `helm version`

Comment: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.0", GitCommit:"8a4aeec08d67a7b84472007529e8097ec3742105", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.14.7"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clone the git repo

```
git clone https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge.git
```

Then use below command with helm 3. Notice `--name` is not needed with helm 3

```
helm install --namespace kube-system ingress-merge ingress-merge/helm
```

or below command with helm 2

```
helm install --namespace kube-system --name ingress-merge ingress-merge/helm
```